# Battery drain on ubuntu is fast

Tags: battery, power-management

My battery drain on win7 is less than that of ubuntu (around 45 min of difference).
Can you advice me something to get best battery performance on my laptop?
when I decrease the brightness it remains fine for the session but increases on boot?

Is there a software to manage my power saving on my laptop?