# Ubuntu using up battery power too quickly

Tags: laptop, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery drain on ubuntu is fast.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9817/battery-drain-on-ubuntu-is-fast)

I use dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop. My windows 7 easily runs for about 2 hours on battery.

The problem is Ubuntu uses up all the battery in about an hour.

Is there anyway to manage power more efficiently in Ubuntu?