# Fast battery consumption on Samsung PABAS024

Tags: 11.10, battery

I have a Lenovo 3000 N100 and my battery gets low real fast (sorry for bad English)

i read somewhere to execute `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info` and check out design and last full capacity if they match that it is good if they don't my battery is properly dead/broken

well as you can see they match

```
present:                 yes

design capacity:         4800 mAh

last full capacity:      4800 mAh

battery technology:      rechargeable

design voltage:          11100 mV

design capacity warning: 420 mAh

design capacity low:     156 mAh

cycle count:          0

capacity granularity 1:  264 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  3780 mAh

model number:            PABAS024

serial number:           3658Q

battery type:            LION

OEM info:                SAMSUNG
```

After that I did some googling and thought I found a fix. I added `pcie_aspm=force` to `/etc/default/grub`. I fully charged the battery but still when I take out the adapter I immediately get message box that says `battery critically low`. Then when it gets in sleep mode and i connect my adapter again and wakes up from hibernation my screen is all white and black.

I found in [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9817/battery-drain-on-ubuntu-is-fast) that you should put `aspm=force` in this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"` and not in a seperate line
when i did that immediatly to 2 min then to 27 min then 24 min then 15/22/19/11/12/8/5/1

43 min battery, but hibernation still crashes

How do I solve this?

Comment: have you ever run another OS on this machine? if yes how was the battery performance for that OS. I ask this because its a real possibility that your battery is damaged and needs replacement.

Comment: i had windows 7 on it but battery newer discharge so fast i also had Ubuntu 10.10/11.04 although still quick with discharge newer very fast and newer crashed after coming out of sleep mode

Comment: So is the problem fast battery consumption or hibernation crashing?

Comment: Your battery is dead. They only last about a year.

Comment: In my experience, batteries last longer than a year assuming you take good care of them (my laptop's battery now only stores about 50% its original capacity when fully charged, but I can still run a couple hours off of it and it's almost four years old).