# Short Battery life for dell xps 15z

Tags: dell

I bought dell xps 15z and installed Ubuntu 11.10 on this laptop.
Laptop and ubuntu liked me. 
But I have problem with battery life.
In windows it can 4-5 hours, but in ubuntu it is not more 2 hours.
Can I do something
8GB Ram , Intel i7, Nvidia Gt525 2Gb, ...

Thanks for helps

---

Linked Question:

- [Battery drain on ubuntu is fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9817)

Comment: flagged to be reopened pending answer from http://askubuntu.com/users/2638/brandon-bertelsen

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some other users have had the same problems... 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883714

**tl;dr**

> It looks like the issue has been found. one of our user noticed that if you completely disable the Nouveau drivers and kernel module it resolves the problem. You can find out how here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troublesho...abling_nouveau

and

you can also try following the instructions [here](http://www.ivegotavirus.com/blog/2011/11/06/how-to-get-optimus-working-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/) and get Optimus working..

**snippet**

> Optimus is an optimization technology created by Nvidia to save battery life by automatically switching the power of the graphics processing unit (GPU) off when it is not needed and switching it on when needed again, this is not supported by Nvidia in Linux but there are ways to get it working almost perfectly.
>   This is how I got it working on my Dell XPS 15 L502x with GT540m.

Comment: Unfortunately, a number of these links are dead. A good example of why information needs to be brought into askubuntu and referenced.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is specific to Nvidia Optimus laptops (Nvida 540m, in this case) and is fixed largely by the power management capabilities of `bumblebee`:

From: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

For 12.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

For 11.04 and Older (10,9,8...etc)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Even without re-logging, I watched my battery time go from "1:25" to "3:10".

Answer (score 1):

i think should help you.

TLP packages are available for Arch, Debian, Fedora, Gentoo and Ubuntu. TLP runs on every laptop brand, but setting the battery charge thresholds is available for IBM/Lenovo ThinkPads only.

The best part, TLP comes with a default configuration already optimized for battery life. Install it once and you don’t have to worry about anything. TLP is a pure command line tool with automated background tasks. It does not contain a GUI.
Install TLP on Ubuntu 14.04

The same set of instruction and commands can also be used to install TLP on Ubuntu 14.04 as well as Linux Mint 13 and 17 but not LMDE.

Before installing TLP, make sure “laptop-mode-tools” is not installed. You must remove “laptop-mode-tools” as it conflicts with TLP. Open the Terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

Now run the following commands to install TLP by using its official PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Please remember, TLP will start automatically on startup, but for the first time you must start it manually. Run the following command to start TLP manually:

```
sudo tlp start
```

There are also some optional packages you can install to improve battery life in Linux Ubuntu with TLP. You can install the  optional packages via package management tools (Ubuntu Software Center, Synaptic, …) or terminal command. Run the following command to install the optional TLP packages:

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

ThinkPads require an additional:

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-tools
```

You can also install smartmontools, needed to display disk drive S.M.A.R.T. data and ethtool, needed to disable wake on lan. Run the following command to install smartmontools and ethtool:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools ethtool
```

You can also install TLP packages for other Linux distributions: Debian 6.0+, Arch Linux, openSUSE 11.4+, Gentoo, Fedora 16 and others. For detailed installation instructions see the TLP [homepage](http://linrunner.de/en/).

you can refer [here](http://sourcedigit.com/12715-install-tlp-ubuntu-14-04-reduce-overheating-increase-battery-life/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Jupiter, an aplett, which changes power saving settings beside regulating the CPU frequency.

[Jupiter at webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html)

A lot of peaople gain savings up to 30%.