# Why is Ubuntu so power-inefficient?

Tags: windows, laptop, power-management, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery drain on ubuntu is fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9817/battery-drain-on-ubuntu-is-fast)

I'm currently getting 7–8 hours of battery life whilst using Windows, but I only get about 3 hours in Ubuntu?  Why the big gap?

Some theories of mine:

1. Specialised/optimised drivers in Windows
2. More resource usage in Ubuntu
3. Lack of effective power-saving feature in Ubuntu, vs. Windows, which specifically tries to reduce battery usage when on battery power
4. Dell has a conspiracy with Microsoft.

Seriously, though.  I have a 9-cell battery; I should be getting much better life, right?

Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: acpi has always been a little lacking on the OSS side.  drivers have to be reverse engineered for most things.  this is probably most of the problem.

Comment: @aking1012, no, acpi is largely up to the bios.  It just provides the kernel with tables of data and code that tell it what to do, so there is nothing to reverse engineer.

Comment: @Caesium: I'm already using pm-powersave, CPU Freq. throttling, and powertop.  They didn't really help.  The gap between Windows and Ubuntu is really too large.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 0):

There is a kernel bug causing this, but it's easy to fix:

In terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

And make it look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

Finally, in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: aspm isn't going to make a significant difference because the amount of power spent driving the pci express bus is minimal.

Comment: Bug is yet to be fixed