# Battery power indicator bug and high power consumption on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, indicator, battery, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery drain on ubuntu is fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9817/battery-drain-on-ubuntu-is-fast)

I have a Samsung NP530U3B-A01:
 - intel core i5 2467M
 - 4gb ram
 - intel hd 3000
 - 500gb hard drive

It's dual boot with windows 7. 
I've seen if i unplug the baterry charger, the battery indicator remains as if is still charging and the oposite happens to.

And the power comsunption is HUGE. In windows 7 i got comsuptions around 7w in idle. In Ubuntu 12.04 is around 18w in idle.

I really like ubuntu but with this power consumption i can only got 1h of battery and i dont want to use an OS that can't give me a nice battery life :(

Comment: Can you try to install Jupiter? It's an "appindicator designed to improve laptops / netbooks battery life"
From [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks

Comment: I think he is asking how to change the time remaining to battery percentage? I got to admit I really hate looking at time remaining and would prefer to see percentage. The option was there in 11.04, I don't understand why it was taken out. Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the $Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: there's two questions here - one is about the high usage and the other is about the battery indicator - I came here looking for a solution on the first :/